# Compiling and installing OpenSSH android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssh

hi i am following this guide (https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android) on compiling and installing OpenSSH for Android NDK and get the following error when i execute this command:

```
sudo -E make install CC=$ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc RANLIB=$ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN/arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib
```

The error below:

```
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `install'.
making install in tools...
installing libcrypto.a
/bin/sh: /arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib: No such file or directory
```

Am not sure where it is trying to find this file or what this file is?

Comment: Where does `$ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN` point to?

Comment: Nowhere, based on the error message.

Comment: points to "$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/toolchains/$_ANDROID_EABI/prebuilt/$host/bin"

Answer (score 0):

I had to execute export ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN= /path/to/toolchain again as the setEnv-android.sh did not set the toolchain environment for some odd reason